Notional Value of Worldwide ETD vs OTC Open Interest
I request assistance to find the Notional Value of Worldwide Open Interest of Exchange Traded Derivatives (ETD). As per this FIA link, the total open interest at the end of April 2024 was 1.33 billion contracts.
I seek to compare this data with Notional Value of Worldwide Open Interest of Over the counter (OTC) Derivatives. As per data from BIS, the Notional Value of all OTC derivatives stands at 667 trillion USD.
This WFE link suggests that commodity derivatives alone have a Notional Value of about 200 trillion USD.
This BIS link suggests that the notional value of interest rate and FX based ETD is around 87 billion USD. The BIS does not compile XTD statistics for equity, commodity or credit derivatives contracts, or for derivatives that reference non-standard underlying instruments (eg inflation, weather or energy contracts).
It is usually mentioned that OTC markets are several orders of magnitudes larger than Exchange Traded markets. However, it seems that ETD and OTC markets are not very different.
It would be great if someone can help me check if what I see is correct.

Just a comment. You have to be very careful when you compare open interest in ETD vs OTC markets.
Even though open interest in OTC markets tends to be much higher than in ETD, it isn't necessarily a reflection of market participants carrying more "risk" in OTC vs ETD.
Simple example: ETD are standardized contracts and there are only so many of them. If I buy 3 month SOFR future, the open interest increases by one lot. If I the next day sell the same SOFR future, the open interest decreases one lot, and I have a zero open interest position.
Consider the same dynamic in the OTC markets. Today I receive on a 10Y swap on some notional amount. My open interest increases by some number. Next day I pay on a 10Y swap to offset the risk.
From a risk perspective, there is close to zero risk in this position, but because the contract specs are different: One day different settlement date, likely a different rate etc. The contracts don't net, and the open interest grosses up.
So to sum it up: Open interest in OTC grosses up because you can only net trades when every single trade characteristic matches. in ETD the contract specs always match by design because they are standardized.

Re the last part, there are services like compression which are made to exactly net off risks and open (but similar) trades for this purpose. Most compression is risk free but there is also the concept of risky compression. Lastly IMM dated swaps have also become popular, this being a reason

There are generally significant incentives for people to keep clean books versus clearing houses. Operational costs / risks aside, your friendly clearing house will likely also charge you some on going maintenance fee per open line item.

Might have been an oversimplification. Compression sure does help a lot, and we are doing them on a near daily basis where I am in some shape or form, but you'll never get down to the gross nationals of an ETD book unless everyone exclusively starts trading IMM swaps.
