Derivatives: Value vs Notional/Principal amount
I am reading "Options, Futures and other Derivatives" by John Hull. In chapter 1, a section on OTC market size has the following lines.

Figure 1.1 compares (a) the estimated total principal amounts underlying transactions that were outstanding in the over-the-counter markets between June 1998 and December 2019 and (b) the estimated total value of the assets underlying exchange-traded contracts during the same period. Using these measures, the size of the over-the-counter market in December 2019 was \$558.5 trillion and the size of the exchange-traded market was \$96.5 trillion.


In interpreting Figure 1.1, we should bear in mind that the principal underlying an over-the-counter transaction is not the same as its value. An example of an over-the-counter transaction is an agreement to buy 100 million U.S. dollars with British pounds at a predetermined exchange rate in 1 year. The total principal amount underlying this transaction is \$100 million. However, the value of the transaction might be only \$1 million. The Bank for International Settlements estimates the gross market value of all over-the-counter transactions outstanding in December 2019 to be about $11.6 trillion.

I did not understand how "value" is calculated. In case of options, there is a premium involved that could be the value, but here the example appears to be of FX futures. Its not profit since the transactions are still outstanding. Please help me differentiate "Value" from "Notional/principal amount".
More importantly, why not use "Notional Amount" to compare ETD and OTC markets? The numbers are sourced from Bank for International Settlements. Other free data sources on derivative markets also show data that is difficult to compare. See this question. It is usually mentioned that OTC markets are several orders of magnitudes larger than Exchange Traded markets. However, it "seems" that the sizes of ETD and OTC markets are not very different now.

Value is the present value usually of a trade. For eg a bonds pv is the value of all its future cash flows discounted to today, I.e. if I go and sell this bond today, how much cash can I expect to receive. Notional, is more the size of the trade, I.e. the face value of the trade. 100m notional value of 10y bonds today might only have a value (present) of 70m. Notional is more to do with the quantity of the underlying asset one is transacting. So in fx, 100m notional eur/usd fwd is you being obligated to buy 100m eur for usd at a certain price (call it F) in the future. 100m is the Notional.

At any point though, the value of this asset is really how much you can sell this obligation for. So in USD the value of this is roughly 100m x (F'-F), where F' is the new fwd price.

Yes, you understod correctly, value is the "market value" as assessed by the market-place (assumed to consist of many knowledgeable buyers and sellers), for an option it is the premium, for a bet it is the expected value of the bet, etc. (For ex. if I have made bet to receive 1 USD if my football team wins, the notional amount is 1 USD but the value could be 0.1 USD if my team has little chance to win). There are people whose job it is to assess the value of contracts whose results are in your words "still outstanding".

If you have made a committment to deliver 1 million of a foreign currency at a fixed rate one year hence, what is your risk? If the currency appreciates, you will have a loss as a result of having to deliver the currency at the "wrong" (i.e. below market) rate you agreed. Given that major currency typical yearly fluctuation is 8%, it is is clear that  even in a "bad scenario" (movement even worse than the typical 8%)  the loss is a small fraction of 1 million.

Thanks for the responses. How do the people whose job it is to assess the value of contracts do it ? Is it VaR and/or SPAN + exposure margins. Any estimate of value before the futures transaction is closed is just an estimate. At times of extreme market movements, the "value" can sky-rocket and stay miniscule during calm markets. Atleast for options, the premium is an "observable" metric. The larger point is that if "value" is an estimate, why use it to compare ETD and OTC markets? I have another open question on the size of ETD vs OTC derivative markets on stackexchange

Hull's is not a good book to learn "the product". I'm not sure which one is, but not his for for sure. Maybe The Divine Proportions of Luca Pacioli by W.A.W. Parker is a good start? :)
An option is an instance of a financial contract, whose present value is what you'd need to pay/receive to enter into/terminate a similar contract now. Contracts, in turn, are an instance of assets.
Quants are sometimes tasked with building pricing models that value assets, typically more unusual ones. Quants have many other kinds of models besides pricing. Quants don't run Black-Scholes option pricing models all day, as some journalists write :)
I will adduce a simile that I heard many years ago from Emanuel Derman, which helped me understand what pricing models do.
Suppose that you own a house (the American dream:).  Even if you're not looking to sell it right now, there are many reasons why an estimate of how much you might get for it might be useful.
Example 1. In much of the US, some local government official will sometimes very approximately estimate the market value of some property, and then the property owner will be forced to pay some property tax set as a fraction of its value. Note how the property's square footage can be accurately measured, and behaves a little like the notional here, in that if two properties are identical in most material respects, except for their sizes, then the ratio of their assessed values will be close to the ratio of their sizes. (In some jurisdictions, they don't use projected estimates, but only the last price for which the house was actually bought.)
Example 2. You want a home equity line of credit, in other words, you want to borrow some money, pledging the house as collateral. Or, you're divorcing your spouse, and need to divvy up the house. As part of the process, some independent real estate person will also estimate the value of your house using a more complicated model, taking into consideration the prices paid recently for nearby houses, and adjusting these prices for the differences between other houses and yours. Many, but not all, pricing models use similar principles. "A house down the block was recently sold for $\\\$n$, but they have granite counter tops in the kitchen, and you don't, so yours is $\\\$m$ cheaper."
Accountants talk about two kinds of values for an asset. A "fair value" is what you'd get if you try to unwind the asset under normal market conditions, and a "prudent value" is what what you might get under "fire sale" conditions. If you're "motivated" to sell your house quickly, you might agree to "prudent" lowball offer, rather than wait and hold out for a "fair" one.

Thanks for the insightful response. But the bigger question is that if "value" is an estimate, why use it to compare ETD and OTC markets? The statistics I quoted are sourced from Bank for International Settlements. It would be more informative to compare the size of two types of derivative markets. However, based on the https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/79611/notional-value-of-worldwide-etd-vs-otc-open-interest it seems that ETD and OTC markets are not very different.

Thanks for your response. But the bigger question is why not use "Notional Amount" to compare ETD and OTC markets? I have edited my question with this.

Hull does not want you to use Notional Amount as a synonym for Value because THEY ARE NOT THE SAME, and for many derivatives Value is far smaller than Notional. That is the only point he is making, to keep these 2 distinct in your mind. Often in the newspapers they are confused. Once you know that, feel free to use notional for comparisons if you wish.

Just to add to @nbbo2 comment, and newspapers/media like drama, 1tn of bad derivatives, is a lot more eye catching than 10mn.

I googled and found a typical example of "clickbait" https://www.dollarsandsense.org/archives/2012/0512bondgraham.html saying that the "notional" is what one party owes ro the other in an interest rate swap.  There are literally hundreds of such articles. Funny in a way.

Summing up the gross notionals is a traditional way of reporting transaction volumes, not only for financial derivatives. For example, you bought 100 million face value of US Treasury obligations and 100 kittens, you sold both the next day, you've traded 200 million face value of debt and 200 kittens. This number changes when new transactions appear, or old ones mature/terminate. On the other hand, the market value serves many other purposes, but doesn't show the transaction volume, and fluctuates depending on market conditions.

Exactly. It makes comparison difficult. I still don't understand why value is used here ? It only seems to serve the purpose of obfuscating.

I think Hull is trying to convey here the profit and loss on financial derivatives is a very tiny fraction of the notional that is used to report volumes. The reader shouldn't confuse the notional with the much smaller possible P&L and related figures.
